# c# dynamic behavior?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, clr, dynamic-language-runtime

I have this code :

```
static dynamic Mean (dynamic x, dynamic y)
{
  return (x + y) / 2;
}


static void Main()
{
  int x = 3, y = 5;
  Console.WriteLine (Mean (x, y)); //this is working
}
```

however the following line failes at runtime :

```
string s = Mean (3, 5); // Runtime error!
```

why is that ?

why `s` can not be set with the *dynamic value* ?

and if so , why `Console.WriteLine (...)` *did* succeed to run with this *dynamic value* ?

### edit

and if if so , how can i make `string s = Mean (3, 5);` work ?

Comment: `s` could be set `dynamic` only if its `dynamic s`, well you say its a string

Comment: string s = Mean (3, 5).ToString();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in this case you're trying to set int value to your string variable.

`Console.WriteLine` automatically do `.ToString()` before writing in console. Try this for example.

```
int x=5;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: hows that related to the tostring methd ?

Comment: string s = Mean (3, 5); is trying is going to set int value to your string variable which gives error.
But Console.WriteLine (Mean (x, y)); is working, because it's theoritacally is the same as Console.WriteLine (Mean (x, y).ToString());

Comment: @V4Vendetta, yes, because of that I wrote theoretically to make it more understandable.

Comment: Also, there is an overload for an `object`, which calls .ToString() on it.

Comment: @ChuckNorris does dynamic is sub of object ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, dynamic variables get their types at runtime. So as object method has .ToString() method your variable has that method too.

Comment: @ChuckNorris yeah but when i write `(Mean (3, 5)).ToString();` - how does he know in compile time that it has ToString () ?

Comment: You can write any function, for example (Mean (3, 5)).MyFunction(); and it will not thorugh compile-time exception. If at runtime your dynamic variable will assign to a type that doesn't have a MyFunction on it it will throw Runtime Exception.

Comment: @Royi declaring a variable as dynamic tells the compiler not to do any type checking including figuring out if a member is valid. So it will not check whether or not .ToString is available the runtime however will check this

Comment: In your case, int type has .ToString() method, so everything is ok.

Comment: whether or not Console.WriteLine calls ToString is unrelated to the problem. The point is that WriteLine accepts an int as its argument and because of that the run time type check suceeds if WriteLine was implemented such that it drew an int directly to screen as pixels and not using .ToString it wouldn´t change a bit for OP

Comment: it's not only dynamic objects that has there type resolved at runtime the difference is that "everything" is concidered valid for dynamic variables at compile time

Answer (score 3):

your code would have to be valid if written statically.

using dynamic simply means that the type checking is deferred until runtime. In your case mean is returning an int. You are therefor trying to assign an int to a string which is not legal.

typewise there not difference between your code and one using the below implementation of mean

```
int Mean(int x, int y){
   return (x+y)/2;
}
```

the statement below would result in a compilation error

```
string s = Mean(3,5);
```

by using dynamic as return type and the type for x and y, you've simply told the compiler not to check the types but to leave the type checking to the runtime. The check is *essentially* the same in your sample code as the one performed by the compiler and the result is also the same. The assignment is illegal.

`Console.WriteLine` has an overload that takes an int so the type checking succeeds and all is well in that case

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine calls the ToString() method on an object. At runtime when you call ToString() on the dynamic object, which is a int, there is no issue. However, in your second example you are essentially trying to put a int into a string, which is why it is complaining.

I believe this would allow you to do what you want.

```
string s = (Mean (3, 5)).ToString();
```

Comment: does dynamic has toString () ? according to VS it does but is it make any sence ?

Comment: Console.Writeline(...) suceeds because it has an overload that accept an argument of the same type as the call to Mean returns. It has nothing to do with whether or not is uses .ToString internally

Comment: at runtime the variable will be a int, which is a object, which has ToString.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic s = Mean (3, 5);
```

or

```
var s = Mean(3, 5);
```